# Request.UrlReferrer doesn;t works in aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The following code for my asp.net site returns null, when I try to open site from link on another site

```
 If Not IsPostBack Then

        Dim referrer As Uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer
        If referrer Is Nothing Then Response.Write("Null") Else 
            Response.Write(referrer.ToString)
        end if 

 end if
```

And it writes "Null" every time. whats wrong?

Comment: Have you using `Response.Redirect` from other site's page? `UrlReferrer` contains `HTTP_REFERRER` header info sent by the browser, check if link on the source page uses proper redirection to destination page.

Comment: Thanks, It means that, when I come from hiperlink only, UrlReferrer doesn't works?

Comment: Right, if the request comes directly from a hyperlink without any previous request `UrlReferrer` contains null/empty value. You can get `UrlReferrer` only when you arrive upon redirection from any other pages.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto  I have changed page from where link comes and now  works PHP script `header(location: mysiteurl')`  but it still writs "Null".